# Custom matrix dot product using lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, optimization

I have an array containing ~80,000 arrays, each of length 6.

```
large = [['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'G']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'H']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'K']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'L']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'M']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'N']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'O' 'X']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'O' 'Y']
         ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'O' 'Z']
         ...
         ]
```

I also have a small array, `small = ['K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P']`.

I need to compare each element of `small` with every element of the sub-arrays in `large`, using a look-up table (pandas dataframe):

```
              Key   A   B    C    D    E
0             A         xx   yy   zz   hh 
1             B     akj      gh   xc   op 
2             C     gh  xx        qq   kbu 
3             D     fg  xx   lk        cbv 
4             E     jhk xx   ry   dsg   
...           ...
```

For each lookup I need to take the value and pass it to a function:

```
def myfunc(val):
    # do something with val...
    return some_number_based_on_val
```

For example, the first comparison might be: `['K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P']` vs `['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F']`, resulting in  `[6,43,76,12,9,1]`. I would then finally, sum those numbers.

**It's essentially a dot-product like operation but with a custom function.**
Therefore, the desired output would be an 80,000x1 array

How do I go about doing this efficiently? Doing this sequentially means doing ~480,000 look ups and it seems to be quite slow.

Comment: This is too generic, unless you can specify your function `myfunc` so that it can be vectorized in certain way, the only apparent answer is *Yes, looping is the way to go*.

Comment: All `myfunc` does is take the value from the lookup table and gets its "score" based on a dict defined elsewhere. E.g.:  `{'xx': 10, 'akj': 12, ...}`

Comment: Can you minimize the scale of your example sets and make sure all elements work together? For example, your provided lookup table does not appear to include the values K-P which means there's no way to test getting a lookup for your provided data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pandas, you can use Pandas' mapping:

```
# build series, assuming `Key` is index of lookup
s = lookup.stack().map({'xx':10, 'akj':12})

# reindex to get the lookup values
mapped_val = s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(large.ravel(), np.tile(small, large.shape[1]))))

# groupby then sum
mapped_val.groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(large.shape[0]), large.shape[1])).sum()
```

Chaining them all together:

```
(lookup.stack().map({'xx':10, 'akj':12})
       .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(large.ravel(), 
                                              np.tile(small, large.shape[1])))
               )
       .groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(large.shape[0]), large.shape[1])).sum()
)
```